# Select option not working in my modal form while its perfectly running in my console

Tags: css, modal-dialog, bootstrap-select

Anyone can help me to fixed my issue, display select option in modal is not working while when i run my console its working fine but don't know why is not working when displaying my modal form. See attach photo below.
[image: modal form]
[image: console]

Here is my ajax code.. i pass it through html return it in to my detail  blade. i use Bootstrap-select v1.13.1

my index blade...

```
 <div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="mymodal" role="dialog" >
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg col-md-12" role="document">

          <div class="modal-content">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                   <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="modal-body col-md-12  mt--4">
               <div class="defectcontainer"></div>
            </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

my script....

```
 $('#mymodal').on('shown.bs.modal',function(e){

         $.ajax({
             url:'{{{ URL::to("getdefectsdataJson") }}}',
             data:
             {
               'coordinate_id':$("#coordinate_id").val(),
             }
         }).done(function(defectdatahtml){
              $(".defectcontainer").html(defectdatahtml);         
         });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to this documentation https://github.com/snapappointments/bootstrap-select . I found the answer to my question.
$('#mymodal').on('shown.bs.modal',function(e){

```
     $.ajax({
                url:'{{{ URL::to("getdefectsdataJson") }}}',
                data:
                {
                'coordinate_id':$("#coordinate_id").val(),
                }
            }).done(function(defectdatahtml){

              $(".defectcontainer").html(defectdatahtml);

  //-------------  i add this funtion to my script. -------------------------------------------------//
  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
                
        });
```

});

Comment: explain what you've changed so we can learn from it. Posting code and link alone may trigger bots to flag for "low quality answer".